Find the center point of ellipse by only 2 points on it and radiuses
For a project, I am requested to find the center point of an ellipse (not necessarily centered), by just 2 points on it and radiuses.
B and E are points on an ellipse (Begin and End of an elliptic arc).
Rx and Ry are the Radiuses
C is the center point (missing!)
As I know the elliptic equation is:
Bx - Cx = Rx * cos(Ba)   // Ba is the angle of "B"
By - Cy = Ry * sin(Ba)
Ex - Cx = Rx * cos(Ea)   // Ea is the angle of point "E"
Ey - Cy = Ry * sin(Ea)

Ba and Ea are unknown, as I am missing the central point. Finding them could help me a lot.
However, even I do:
Cx = Rx * cos(Ba) - Bx
Cx = Rx * cos(Ea) - Ex

and so
Rx * cos(Ba) - Bx = Rx * cos(Ea) - Ex

to find Ba or Ea, this gets very complicated:
cos(Ba) = ( Bx + Rx * cos(Ea) - Ex ) / Rx

and then:
Ba = acos( ( Bx + Rx * cos(Ea) - Ex ) / Rx )

But I cannot solve the content of acos as it has another unknown angle within....
I really feel lost and have no idea what I am doing wrong or maybe there is a better way....?
NOTE:
I am aware that there are 4 possible solutions! I need to find all of the 4.
There are other parameters given (like sweep flag and large angle flag), like in HTML canvas arc() but I am not painting on HTML canvas, and therefore I don't have "arc" function (I am gonna use beziers to paint it, but it is another story).
Thanks a lot for help

What, in your opinion, is the meaning of "Begin and End of an elliptic arc"? The answer might be quite significant in telling you how to solve the problem...

The formulas you use imply that the ellipse's axes are parallel to the known $x$ and $y$ axes. Is that intended as one of the known conditions of the problem?

"Radius" in this context suggests to me a radius of curvature, but you apparently mean that you know the semimajor axis length and the semiminor axis length.

Yes, at the moment the ellipse's axes are parallel to x and y respectively (not rotated). Rx and Ry imply that I know the length of the semimajor and semiminor - yes, these are Rx and Ry.

Given two points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$ on the ellipses and semi-axes lengths $a, b$ for axes that are axis aligned, the equations for $h, k,$ where $(h,k)$ is a center, in M2 are
R=QQ[x1,y1,x2,y2,a,b][h,k,MonomialOrder=>Lex]
I=ideal((x1-h)^2*b^2+(y1-k)^2*a^2-a^2*b^2,(x2-h)^2*b^2+(y2-k)^2*a^2-a^2*b^2)
gens gb I

Yielding a quadratic in $k$ so generally there's max two real solutions:
$${\small (4y_1^2a^4-8y_1y_2a^4+4y_2^2a^4+4x_1^2a^2b^2-8x_1x_2a^2b^2+4x_2^2a^2b^2)k^2+}\\{\tiny (-4y_1^3a^4+4y_1^2y_2a^4+4y_1y_2^2a^4-4y_2^3a^4-4x_1^2y_1a^2b^2+8x_1y_1x_2a^2b^2-4y_1x_2^2a^2b^2-4x_1^2y_2a^2b^2+8x_1x_2y_2a^2b^2-4x_2^2y_2a^2b^2)k+}\\{\tiny y_1^4a^4-2y_1^2y_2^2a^4+y_2^4a^4+2x_1^2y_1^2a^2b^2-4x_1y_1^2x_2a^2b^2+2y_1^2x_2^2a^2b^2+2x_1^2y_2^2a^2b^2-4x_1x_2y_2^2a^2b^2+2x_2^2y_2^2a^2b^2+x_1^4b^4-4x_1^3x_2b^4+6x_1^2x_2^2b^4-4x_1x_2^3b^4+x_2^4b^4-4x_1^2a^2b^4+8x_1x_2a^2b^4-4x_2^2a^2b^4=0}\\
{\small(2x_1b^2-2x_2b^2)h+(2y_1a^2-2y_2a^2)k-y_1^2a^2+y_2^2a^2-x_1^2b^2+x_2^2b^2=0}$$
Changing the roles of $a$, and $b$ there are four solution ellipses. 
